# Is frame dragging accelerating asteroids or cometes that after passing fairly close to the gravitational source move away?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, frame-dragging

What is interesting but also confusing for me,if this is true, is that if frame dragging somehow gives a'kick' to a highly elliptical orbiting object it seems that this object cannot orbit for so long as after several revolutions frame dragging forces it to gain more and more speed and finnaly helps it to get free of the gravity of the massive rotating object? The second possibility is that the orbiting object gains speed only in the frame dragging zone but after leaving it it is left with its intrinsic speed.So what is true?

Answer (score 0):

If the test particle's mass and size are neglible compared to the black hole, its axial orbital angular momentum $L_z$ and its total energy in the bookkeeper's frame $E=E_{\rm kin}+E_{\rm pot}+m c^2$ are [conserved quantities](https://i.ibb.co/nf6kdgT/Unbenannt.png), so if you don't utilize the [Blandford Znajek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blandford%E2%80%93Znajek_process) or the [Penrose process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process) to exchange energy and angular momentum your second option is true and the test particle will return with the same energy it had when it left.